# Проект в Webstorm: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:1234/upload/' from origin 'http://localhost:63342' has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: cors, webstorm

Запускаю проект на js в WebStorm по адресу http://localhost:1234 (в терминале npm run serve) и отдельно запускаю там же дебаг на страницу index.html (через конфигурацию дебага) по адресу http://localhost:63342/директория проекта/src/index.html
По второму адресу нажимаю кнопку, по нажатию на которую выбираю файл, который должен грузиться в файл в http://localhost:1234/upload, но получаю отлуп в сабже
Что только не пробовал:

1. плагины в хром не помогают - попробовал 3 разных
2. редактировал index.js по адресу node_modules/cors, в начало вставлял например

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.options('*', cors());
```

и всякие другие сочетания - не помогает

3. добавил плагин поддержки .htaccess, где прописал одну строку

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin '*'
```

Тоже не помогает. Помогите побороть плиз уже замучался

Comment: В общем избавился от этой ошибкой установкой прокси как тут указано https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883211/why-does-my-http-localhost-cors-origin-not-work?rq=2          Но сейчас получаю новую ошибку "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)". Как побороть затык может кто-нибудь все таки подскажет?